# How to find common name from index(first) column using python?

Tags: python, pandas

find common name from index(first) column using python and sum it's following column from same row.

### For example I have below two csv.

```
df1
Name   sub1 sub2 sub3
 X      1     2    5                
 Y      4     5    6  

df2
Name    sub1  sub2  sub3
 A        3      5     3
 Y        3      1     4
```

Output should display only Y in first column as common and display column contents as df2 but in sub3 column it should average from df1 and df2.

```
output

Name   sub1     sub2      sub3
Y      3(df2)   1(df2)     5=(df1+df2)/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you:-

```
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.DataFrame([['X', 1, 2, 5],['Y', 4, 5, 6]], columns = ["Name", "sub1", "sub2","sub3"]) 
df2= pd.DataFrame([['A', 3, 5, 3],['Y', 3,1, 4]], columns = ["Name", "sub1", "sub2","sub3"]) 

joindeDf = df1.append(df2).groupby("Name").agg({"sub3":"mean", "Name":"count"}).query("Name > 1")
joindeDf.drop("Name", axis = 1, inplace = True)
df2.drop("sub3", axis = 1, inplace = True)
df2.index = df1.Name
opDF = df2.merge(joindeDf, left_index=True, right_index=True, how = 'inner')
print opDF
```

Output:-

```
        Name    sub1    sub2    sub3 
Name                 
 Y       Y        3       1      5
```

Comment: it's perfect on my real csv sheet after all parameter change. thank you Rakesh Kumar.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, How is it possible to get output of column sub2 is average of df1 sub2 and df2 sub2. here I want it as 3 instead of 1. rest output should as previous.

Comment: @hk' {"sub2":"mean",  "sub3":"mean", "Name":"count"}

Answer (score 1):

Pandas merge with on = 'Name' will give you only the rows with common name. You can then drop unnecessary columns and find mean of sub3 like this.

```
df_result = pd.merge(df2, df1, on = 'Name')
df_result['sub3'] = df_result[['sub3_x', 'sub3_y']].mean(axis = 1)
df_result = df_result.drop(['sub3_x','sub1_y','sub2_y','sub3_y'], axis = 1)
df_result.columns = ['Name', 'sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3']
```

Resulting dataframe

```
    Name    sub1    sub2    sub3
0   Y       3       1       5
```

Comment: Hi A-Za-z, Your answers also run on my actual data. thank you for your easy to understand answer.